# Indexing of array in rpy2

Tags: python, arrays, r, indexing, rpy2

I just started using Python resp. Rpy2 so I am really a beginner.
So far I manage to get my own R-package loaded via Rpy2
and a result for my input variables is produced (comparable
to the lm() function of R).
My result is a following:

```
>>> res
<ListVector - Python:0x1561828 / R:0xe6a5c8>
[Matrix, Array]
  coef.f: <class 'rpy2.robjects.vectors.Matrix'>
  [-10.554713, 1.640681, 0.957045, ..., 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.783108]
  pred.f: <class 'rpy2.robjects.vectors.Array'>
  [17.189366, 7.116058, 41.526062, ..., 459.952946, 312.088634, 677.908581]
```

I am also able to get the array subpart (pred.f) by using index 1:

```
>>>res1 = res[1]
>>> res1
<Array - Python:0x1561850 / R:0x4b299d0>
[17.189366, 7.116058, 41.526062, ..., 459.952946, 312.088634, 677.908581]
>>> print res1
, , L=300, AR=1.5, SO=1, T=30

    sigma_stat sigma_mob
fit  17.189366 152.21461
lwr   7.116058  76.98245
upr  41.526062 301.01379

, , L=300, AR=1.5, SO=2, T=30

    sigma_stat sigma_mob
fit   27.62310  284.5423
lwr   14.54639  173.3316
upr   52.45825  467.1449

, , L=300, AR=1.5, SO=3, T=30

    sigma_stat sigma_mob
fit   39.75894  459.9529
lwr   24.07098  312.0886
upr   65.67369  677.9086
```

Now I'd like to use a intelligent way to access certain numbers in this array.
Eg. I'd like the number for sigma_stat,fit,L=300,AR=1.5,SO=3,T=30 ... this means
my array is 6-dimensional.

Is there an easy way to do that? Something like indexing using the dimension names/numbers: res1('sigma_stat','fit','L'=300,'AR'=1.5,'SO'=3,'T'=30)

Thank you for your help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like this work ?

```
res1.rx('sigma_stat', 'fit', 'L=300', 'AR=1.5', 'SO=3', 'T=30')
```

(note that the dimension names must in the right order - I don't that the time to test, may be 'sigma_stat' and 'fit' should go to the end of the argument list)